# String functions - replaceAll not working for "."

Tags: java, string

I was going through `replaceAll` function. I had following string:

```
String str = "com.sac.src.abc.def";
```

I had to replace all dot's with `/`.So I tried

```
str.replaceAll(".","/");
```

But what I was getting was,that my string converted to -

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: The first argument to `replaceAll` is a regular expression, not just a string, and `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` means "any character". You need to escape it:

```
"\\."
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replaceAll, use replace method like:

```
str.replace(".","/");
```

"." is a special character in REGEX world and replaceAll takes regex as first input parameter in the method. Since you are not using regex already, use replace method.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a *special character* which *matches any single character*. You have to escape it use `\\.`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scape `.` with `\\.` . `.` means any character.

```
str.replaceAll("\\.","/");
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since `dot(.)` matches any character you need two backslashes before the dot, one to escape the slash so it gets through, and the other to escape the dot so it becomes literal.

```
String str = "com.sac.src.abc.def";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\.","/"));
```